# Counter up or down script not working python

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, counter

I'm trying to create a script that counts up if start < stop or count down is start < stop. I'm getting part of the output but not all. Any tips?

```
def counter(start, stop):
x = start
if x > stop:
    return_string = "Counting down: "
    while x > stop:
        return_string += str(x)
        if x == stop:
            return_string += ","
        return return_string
else:
    return_string = "Counting up: "
    while x <= stop:
        return_string += str(x)
        if x == stop:
            return_string += ","
        break
return return_string
```

```
         print(counter(1, 10)) # Should be "Counting up: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"
         print(counter(2, 1)) # Should be "Counting down: 2,1"
         print(counter(5, 5)) # Should be "Counting up: 5"
```

Comment: Please post the output you get so we can see what you mean when you say you are 'getting part of the output but not all'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the errors you made:

1. You already `break` the loop on the first iteration
2. You add the comma only when you reach stop which is exactly when no comma is needed anymore
3. that `if x == stop` can never be true because of the enclosing loop's termination condition `while x > stop`
4. For the same reason, `stop` itself is never added to the output

The following changes will fix your function:

```
def counter(start, stop):
    x = start
    if x > stop:
        return_string = "Counting down: "
        while x > stop:
            return_string += str(x)+","
            x -= 1
    else:
        return_string = "Counting up: "
        while x < stop:
            return_string += str(x)+","
            x += 1
    return_string += str(stop)
    return return_string

>>> counter(1,2)
'Counting up: 1,2'
>>> counter(1,5)
'Counting up: 1,2,3,4,5'
>>> counter(5,1)
'Counting down: 5,4,3,2,1'
>>> counter(5,2)
'Counting down: 5,4,3,2'
```

Answer (score 1):

THIS WORKED FOR ME

```
def counter(start, stop):
x = start
if x>stop:
    return_string = "Counting down: "
    while x >= stop:
        return_string += str(x)
        if x!=stop:
            return_string += ","
        x-=1
else:
    return_string = "Counting up: "
    while x <= stop:
        return_string += str(x)
        if x!=stop:
            return_string += ","
        x+=1
return return_string
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def counter(start, stop):
    x = start
    if x > stop:
        return_string = "Counting down: "
        while x >= stop:
            return_string += str(x)
            if x > stop:
                return_string += ","
            x -= 1 
    else:
        return_string = "Counting up: "
        while x <= stop:
            return_string += str(x)
            if x < stop:
                return_string += ","
            x +=1
    return return_string

print(counter(1, 10)) # Should be "Counting up: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"
print(counter(2, 1)) # Should be "Counting down: 2,1"
print(counter(5, 5)) # Should be "Counting up: 5"
```

Comment: You could improve the quality of your answer by providing a description of what you've changed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the built-in `range` function to get the list of numbers and then use join to place the comma between the values. Much more succinct.

```
def counter(start,stop):
    if start <= stop:
        output = "Counting Up: "
    else:
        output = "Counting Down: "
    direction = 1 if start <= stop else -1
    output += ",".join(map(str,range(start,stop+direction,direction)))
    return output

print(counter(1, 10)) # Should be "Counting up: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"
print(counter(2, 1)) # Should be "Counting down: 2,1"
print(counter(5, 5)) # Should be "Counting up: 5
```

Gives

```
Counting Up: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
Counting Down: 2,1
Counting Down: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

every answers is almost correct but no one noticed that their code added an extra "," at the last of every answers

```
def counter(start, stop):
    x = start
    if x>stop:
        return_string = "Counting down: "
        while x >= stop:
            return_string += str(x)
            x = x-1
            if x >= stop:
                return_string += ","
    else:
        return_string = "Counting up: "
        while x <= stop:
            return_string += str(x)
            x = x + 1
            if x <= stop:
                return_string += ","
    return return_string

print(counter(1, 10)) # Should be "Counting up: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"
print(counter(2, 1)) # Should be "Counting down: 2,1"
print(counter(5, 5)) # Should be "Counting up: 5"
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    def counter(start, stop):
        x = start
        if x > stop:
            return_string = "Counting down: "
            while x > stop:
                return_string += str(x)+","
                x -= 1
        else:
            return_string = "Counting up: "
            while x < stop:
                return_string += str(x)+","
                x += 1
        return_string += str(stop)+'"'
        return return_string
print(counter(1, 10)) # Should be "Counting up: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"
print(counter(2, 1)) # Should be "Counting down: 2,1"
print(counter(5, 5)) # Should be "Counting up: 5
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.